# Как парвильно запретить файл в .htaccess

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess

Здравствуйте! У меня такая проблема. Надо запретить вывод картинки по адресу site/images/111.jpg
В .htaccess прописал

```
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Но картинки все равно выводятся. Закинул на каждый уровень папок. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> надо запретить вывод картинки по адресу site/images/111.jpg

В каталоге site/images/ .htaccess след содержания:

Если только указанную картинку, то достаточно

```
<Files "111.jpg">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Если графику по маске, то

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```